# AWS Load Balancer Health Check Path for Laravel App

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-application-load-balancer, laravel-forge

I have 2 AWS EC2 instances sitting behind an Application Load Balancer. On each instance I have multiple multi-tenant Laravel apps deployed (app1.com, app2.com). As they are multi-tenant they'll have wildcard subdomains (demo.app1.com, demo.app2.com etc...)

Laravel Forge has a `000-catch-all` nginx file in the `sites-available/` folder which returns a status code of 444.

I'm trying to figure out what path I need to set for the target groups in AWS that will return a healthy `200` response. No matter what path I set for the health check, it always resolves to the `000-catch-all` file and returns a 444 resulting in an 'unhealthy' instance.

**Things I have tried:**

- Created a route (/health) in one of the apps that simply returns a 200 status code and set the health check path to both `/health` and `demo.app1.com/health`
- Created a server block in both the `000-catch-all` and the `app1.com` files with a server block like,

  `location /health { return 200 'OK'; }`

The only thing that works is if I make the `000-catch-all` file return a 200 instead of a 444 but that seems hacky.

Any ideas or something I might be missing?

Answer (score -1):

1. open 000-catch-all
2. add location block..

```
location /health {
    return 200;
}
location / {
    return 444;
}
```

3. nginx conf reload

```
systemctl reload nginx
```